# Solving This Analysis Problem using an ODE?

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the function
$$f(x) = \int_0^1 y^{\alpha} e^{xy} dy, x > 0,$$

Where $\alpha > 0$ is constant.
While this function is defined for $x > 0$, I would like to show that $f$
can be continuously extended to $x = 0$. I recognized that
$$f'(x) = \int_0^1 y^{\alpha + 1} e^{xy} dy,$$
and if I set $u = y^{\alpha + 1} \implies du = (\alpha+1) y^{\alpha} dy$
and $dv = e^{xy} dy \implies v = \frac{e^{xy}}{x}$, we see that
$$f'(x) = \int udv = uv - \int vdu$$
$$ (y^{\alpha + 1} \frac{e^{xy}}{x})_{y=0}^{y=1} - 
\int_0^1 \frac{e^{xy}}{x} (\alpha + 1)y^{\alpha} dy$$
$$=\frac{e^x}{x} -\frac{\alpha+1}{x} \int_0^1 y^{\alpha} e^{xy} dy$$
$$=\frac{e^x}{x} -\frac{\alpha+1}{x} f(x).$$

I was advised that I can solve for a non-integral version of $f(x)$
by playing around with this equation, but I am not completely sure how to use
ODEs to solve this problem. Any recommendations?

Comment: The integral is well defined for all $x.$ What's so special about $0?$

Comment: Surely $f(0) = \int_0^1 y^\alpha dy$?